# How to check transactions of an address that spent ether to a contract?

Tags: web3js, transactions, tokens, addresses

Am not sure if the question was already asked somewhere, I tried searching but couldn't get it.

This is what I have done so far.

1. Created and deployed Token Contract
2. Created and deployed CrowdSale Contract

Now, how do I list out the transactions sent by an address (person) to the crowdsale Contract to buy the token. I checked the codes to know the number of tokens bought by the address, but I also want to show the number of ethers he sent at various phases of the crowdsale. I know there is API endpoint to pull out the transactions of an address, but here I want to get the transaction done only with the CrowdSale Contract.

Hope I was able to explain the need. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally my apporach is to use events inside contract which is pretty easy to list Transaction detail with specific information e.g

In contract i define event like this

```
event buy(address indexed customerAddress, uint priceValue, uint amount);
```

Then in js file like this

```
var buyEevent= contractInstance.buy({customerAddress:customerAddress},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
            buyEvent.watch(function(error, response) {
                 if (!error) {
                      console.log("event: "+response.args.customerName);
                      console.log("event: "+response.args.priceValue);
                      console.log("event: "+response.args.amount);

                 } else {
                      console.error(error);
                 }
            });
```

Hope it may be helpfull for you.

Comment: Thanks. Guess `purchaseEvent.watch` should be changed to `buyEevent.watch`

Comment: thanks for correction @Rajesh , i make changes to my solution so, i forget to change name there